# Problema com resolução do AVD

Tags: android, apache-cordova, app, avd

Configurei conforme o curso que estou fazendo mandou, mas ficou uma porcaria a resolução do meu AVD.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A resolução da tela do emulador vai somente importar caso você queira fazer uma aplicação com os componentes em posição fixa, ou no caso de fazer um app com vários tamanhos de tela, se não for esse o caso, recomendo simplesmente escolher uma das predefinições que a configuração do avd disponibiliza

Comment: Mas no caso, eu utilizei, e mesmo assim ele fez isso, Eu usei a ultima do Nexus e ficou essa porcaria que está na imagem. Ficou péssimo. Está impossível de trabalhar assim.